# neo4jphp: Cypher and Resultset differ

Tags: neo4j, neo4jphp

seems I am too tired to find the solution, maybe someone has a hint for me.

I have built a graph in Neo4J which I connect via neo4jphp (everyman). Using the java browser the graph looks ok, every user exists one time and might have several groups he belongs to.

While creating the user I use MERGE in order to avoid them to be doubled - like

```
MERGE (user:PERSON {
firstname: "Max",
name: "Muster", 
password:"e52ddddddd9afb7b373f9da437",
title:"something",
login:"Nick",   
status:"active"   
}) 
ON CREATE SET user.uuid = "'.uniqid().'" // PHP function for a UUID
return user;
```

This works well as I see the correct number of users even when I resend the query or reload the page.

The users are connected with a query towards groups like this

```
MATCH (user:PERSON), (team:GROUP)      
WHERE user.name= "Muster" AND user.firstname="Max" AND team.name="LOCAL_USER"
CREATE (user)-[:IS_MEMBER_OF {role:"user", status:"active"}]->(team);
```

Checking this in the GUI of Neo4J shows a correct graph (at least from what I can see). I have the right amount of users and their relations.

When I query the graph directly by Cypher in the browser GUI like this

```
MATCH (user:PERSON {status: "active"})-[relation:IS_MEMBER_OF{status:"active"}]->(team:GROUP {name:"LOCAL_USER"} )
RETURN user
ORDER BY user.name;
```

I get the correct number of users.

When I use the neo4jphp lib (everyman) I receive some users double - the resultset has several elements with the same user. I couldnt figure out why they behave differently but I assume that I might have messed up the relations somehow. But still I am wondering why the same cypher query returns different amount of records when you send it via GUI or via everyman lib and I would need a hint how to change maybe the queries to make sure that I only get one record per user as every user is only one time connected to the LOCAL_USER group.

Thanks for pushing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you get doubles because you have multiple paths (e.g. multiple teams) for the user,
use `RETURN distinct user`

For your import statement, you do it the wrong way round, instead of your approach.

MERGE by unique id (e.g login in your case) and set the other properties with `ON CREATE SET ...`

Also **use parameters** not literal values in your query strings !!

```
MERGE (user:PERSON {login:{login}})
ON CREATE SET
  user.firstname = {firstname}, user.name= {name}, user.password = {password},
  user.title={title}, user.status = {status}, user.uuid = {uuid}
RETURN user;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing link! And also thanks for pointing me to the parameter usage and the altering of the MERGE-statement, tested it and it worked fine! Very appreciated - and so fast :) +1